# Combine uncertainty of multiple measurement instruments.

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to figure out if there exists a significant difference between measurement instruments for RF power measurements. I will measure multiple Bluetooth modules TX-power with 4 different instruments.

Now, let's say I measure one module on all 4 instruments. The spread of the TX-power measurements is 0.15dBm. The measurement uncertainties of the 4 instruments are 0.1dB, 0.2dB, 0.3dB, and 0.5dB.

Is there any way to combine the uncertainties of all the instruments? In other words, have ****one** uncertainty value** that represents **all instruments**. For example, if the combined uncertainty would be 0.2dB, the spread of 0.15dBm would be within instrument uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is to test the hypothesis whever all of the measurements have the same value (up to noise).

To compute one number that quantitatively answers such question you could use likelyhood ratio test.

You could for example assume that each device gives the same value with the prescribed uncertainty and compare it to alternative hypothesis that one of the devices gives values from a distribution with different mean.

You can read how to accomplish this here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

Comment: Yes! So assume all instruments measure the same value, add/subtract the uncertainty, and then compare that to the real measurement data?

Comment: @user294957 Broadly speaking, yes. Mathematising it is a bit harder. You coud, for example, assume all devices give gaussian errors and then likelihood can be computed from squared deviations, then to compute likelihood of alternative hypothesis you would need squared deviations of all but one of the measurements. After some computations you would still need to decide on test boundary - likely based on significance level. This is a bit too involved to fit in the comment. Perhaps there is some better way to communicate?